# Calling a windows .exe (compiler) from Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I would like to know if this is even feasible. And if so, what a possible approach would be.
I am thinking that the .exe would have to be made available through a web service running on a windows stack (asp.net or php) and that a direct heroku solution would not be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you do it as a externally, yes. The main trick there would be making the service on the windows box and making sure your service was secure. If you're going for cloud stuff, your best bet is probably to set your service up on a windows server on EC2 or Rackspace or [insert cloud provider here]. They're not as cheap as linux boxes because of the license cost, but shouldn't be too difficult to manage.

Unless Heroku has changed a lot from the last time I looked at it, the underlying OS was linux of some variety, so it's really unlikely that you could get an windows binary to run internally without bundling wine into your application (probably not worth trying to figure out).